# Posting data to a cell using Google Sheets API

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, postman

I'm pretty new to this sort of stuff and I have spent an entire day trying to figure out how to post data to a cell using the Sheets API...

[Sheets API - Change contents of a cell](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#change_contents_of_a_cell)

The above documentation asks me to create an entry element containing the relevant data (replacing `key`, `worksheetId`, and `cell` with their appropriate values). I have set `Content-Type` to `application/atom+xml`. My code is as follows...

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">
  <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/MY_KEY/od6/public/full/R2C2</id>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/MY_KEY/od6/public/full/R2C2"/>
  <gs:cell row="2" col="2" inputValue="35"/>
</entry>
```

Using Postman, I am able to `GET` data from spreadsheet but when I try to `PUT` the data I get

> "Google Drive -- Page Not Found".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your sheet shared appropriately or public?

Comment: Hi. Yes it is published to the web and anyone with a link can edit. Thanks.